# Rails Bootstrap 4 Nav Tabs Active Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I am on a rails page for products. Within the edit product section I have a nav tab sort of like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-info">Product info</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-images">Images</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If the whole thing is in the product model how can I set the active class based on what tab I am in so that when I upload new product images it stays on that tab when the page reloads and refreshes?

Answer (score -1):

You can use that pretty gem:
https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to

or manually check the `controller_name` and/or `action_name`: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters